# Maven error No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to deploy jar to remote repository. I wrote a maven deploy command for that

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -q -Dfile=$jarf -DgroupId=lsls -DartifactId=$JAR_NAME -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DrepositoryId=internal -Durl= http://XXXXX.com
```

I dont have any project or pom file . I only have a settings.xml file in .m2 folder . I am getting this error

```
 No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups.
```

I have looked up for other solutions but they never worked.

Comment: Remove the space `-Durl= http://XXXXX.com` here...

Comment: thankyou very much. That was a great help. Small thing but wasted my time for very long.

Comment: You welcome. Appreciate to help...